# Are mass terms forbidden in the Lagrangian because of parity violation or because fermions live in a complex representation?

Tags: gauge-theory, standard-model, group-theory, parity

Normally one argues that we can't write down Lorentz AND gauge invariant mass terms, because of parity violation, i.e. l-chiral and r-chiral fields transform differently. This means that mass terms are forbidden in the Lagrangian, **because of** $SU(2)$. (The r-chiral particles are $SU(2)$ doublets and the r-iral particles are $SU(2)$ singlets. We must combine pos. with compelex conjugated neg. chiral particles in order to get sth Lorentz invariant. Because of $SU(2)$ this means we are combining doublets with singlets, which is not invariant under $SU(2)$ and therefore mass terms are forbidden.)

Nevertheless, in [Physics and Geometry](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1986.1/Main/icm1986.1.0267.0306.ocr.pdf) Witten argues that mass terms are forbidden for fermions, because the fermion representation is complex, i.e. $R \neq \tilde R$. As far as I know, the fermion representation is complex **because of** $SU(3)$ and $U(1)$ ($SU(2)$ has no complex representations), but it's $SU(2)$ which is responsible for parity violation. **How do these two arguments fit together?**

*(A similar argument is commonly used in Grand Unified Theories, known as Survival Hypothesis, which states that the SM fermions are light, because they transform according to a complex representation. )*

Comment: The fundamental representation is pseudo real. It is equivalent but not equal to its conjugate representation. Your first paragraph argument is sound. Recall that a *different* Yukawa gives mass to the up quark than the one giving mass to the down quark: If the fundamental were identical to its conjugate, this would simply not be possible.